# iconv cannot convert between CP1256 -t ISO-8859-6

Tags: unix, shell, cygwin

i tried to convert from CP1256 to ISO-8859-6 encoding using Sygwin but it cannot convert!

and help?

```
$ iconv -f CP1256 -t ISO-8859-6 cca.txt > cca1.txt

iconv: cca.txt:791:41: cannot convert
```

the result of `sed -n '791p' cca.txt | od -c`

is [image]

Comment: Please post the output of this command: `sed -n '791p' cca.txt | od -c`

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the character maps for [Windows-1256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) and [ISO-8859-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-6), you can see that 1256 has a character at every point, but 8859-6 has lots of gaps. So when converting, if there's a character that's not in the target encoding, `iconv` will complain.

Depending on which version of `iconv` you have, you may use the `-c` option, and those non-convertible characters will be dropped -- the file will get shorter. Or you can use something like `--unicode-subst="@"`, which will substitute the invalid characters with `@`, which is convertible. Note that there is quite a bit of flexibility with that substitution, including expansion (e.g. `"[%u]"` will convert to the Unicode value in brackets).

If Cygwin does not have these options, you can try a recent Linux or Mac OS X.

In any case, the resulting file can only have characters that are actually in ISO-8859-6.